# Double array with attributes

Tags: objective-c

I've got a `double number` and around 100 another doubles that I need to save somewhere. I don't know, where to save them, because array of doubles does't exist. Then I need to find a number from that 100 doubles which is less than `number`, but it's closest to the `number` from that 100 doubles. This is not a main problem. Main problem is that each number from that 100 numbers must have it's own attribute. There are total 12 attributes.

For example:

```
double number = 100.49382;
double a = 50.4384 , car;
double b = 80.230593 , house;
double c = 90.94830 , tree;
// another doubles less than 90
```

I need to find out that `double c` (from array or somewhere) is closest to `double number` and it has attribute `tree`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which experience do you have with object-orientated programming?

Comment: A little, I'm learning Obj-C.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. I don't want to give an answer that is incomplete or write thousands of words. So just a pointer: You have to create a class with two properties (`double` and `NSString`or whatever `tree` is) and put instances of it into an instance of `NSArray`.

Comment: Thank you. If I won't understand anything, I will write. :)

Answer (score -1):

for me is completely unclear what you are asking.
If you want to store double just use `C` arrays, or wrap the double in `NSNumber` objects.